# Translate WMTS Capabilities XML into JSON layer matrices (QGIS functionality?)

Tags: qgis, wmts, mapfish-print

Using the EPSG:2193 projection from WMTS capabilities for a layer:   https://data.linz.govt.nz/services;key=60c2f93ec4dc45448ff7d93df524eb75/wmts/1.0.0/layer/50767/WMTSCapabilities.xml
I'm trying to produce a JSON layer definition for use in MapFish Print requests.

I can get other WMTS layers to work, but this one is eluding me. I'm wondering if the XML provided by the service is actually correct as it states that each `TileMatrix` has a:

```
<TopLeftCorner>10000000.0 -1000000.0</TopLeftCorner>
```

But the bounding box provided would suggest a different `TopLeftCorner`?

```
<ows:BoundingBox crs="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::2193">
  <ows:LowerCorner>3087000.000000 274000.000000</ows:LowerCorner>
  <ows:UpperCorner>7173000.000000 3327000.000000</ows:UpperCorner>
</ows:BoundingBox>
```

I've tried updating `TopLeftCorner` based on these values, but I'm still not seeing any tiles come through on my maps.

I can pull the WMTS layer into QGIS without issue. Perhaps there's a way I can export the JSON I need from QGIS itself? Looking at the Layer Properties, QGIS also reports a 10000000.0 -1000000.0 top left though.

[image: QGIS screenshot]

The layer JSON I've manually created from the XML capabilities, which doesn't work, is as follows. Can anyone see anything I might be getting wrong?

```
{
    "layout": "A4 portrait",
    "outputFormat": "pdf",
    "geodetic": true,
    "outputFilename": "test-WMTS",
    "attributes": {
        "map": {
            "projection": "EPSG:2193",
            "dpi": 300,
            "rotation": 0,
            "center": [
                1334616, 5064670
            ],
            "scale": 200000,
            "layers": [
                {
                    "type": "WMTS",
                    "baseURL": "https://tiles-a.data-cdn.linz.govt.nz/services;key=60c2f93ec4dc45448ff7d93df524eb75/tiles/v4/layer=50767/EPSG:2193/{TileMatrix}/{TileCol}/{TileRow}.png",
                    "opacity": 1,
                    "layer": "50767",
                    "matrixSet": "EPSG:2193",
                    "matrices": [
                        {
                            "identifier": "0",
                            "matrixSize": [
                                2,
                                4
                            ],
                            "scaleDenominator": 32000000,
                            "tileSize": [
                                256,
                                256
                            ],
                            "topLeftCorner": [
                                10000000.0, -1000000.0
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "identifier": "1",
                            "matrixSize": [
                                4,
                                7
                            ],
                            "scaleDenominator": 16000000,
                            "tileSize": [
                                256,
                                256
                            ],
                            "topLeftCorner": [
                                10000000.0, -1000000.0
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "identifier": "2",
                            "matrixSize": [
                                8,
                                13
                            ],
                            "scaleDenominator": 8000000,
                            "tileSize": [
                                256,
                                256
                            ],
                            "topLeftCorner": [
                                10000000.0, -1000000.0
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "identifier": "3",
                            "matrixSize": [
                                16,
                                25
                            ],
                            "scaleDenominator": 4000000,
                            "tileSize": [
                                256,
                                256
                            ],
                            "topLeftCorner": [
                                10000000.0, -1000000.0
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "identifier": "4",
                            "matrixSize": [
                                31,
                                49
                            ],
                            "scaleDenominator": 2000000,
                            "tileSize": [
                                256,
                                256
                            ],
                            "topLeftCorner": [
                                10000000.0, -1000000.0
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "identifier": "5",
                            "matrixSize": [
                                61,
                                97
                            ],
                            "scaleDenominator": 1000000,
                            "tileSize": [
                                256,
                                256
                            ],
                            "topLeftCorner": [
                                10000000.0, -1000000.0
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "identifier": "6",
                            "matrixSize": [
                                121,
                                193
                            ],
                            "scaleDenominator": 500000,
                            "tileSize": [
                                256,
                                256
                            ],
                            "topLeftCorner": [
                                10000000.0, -1000000.0
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "identifier": "7",
                            "matrixSize": [
                                242,
                                386
                            ],
                            "scaleDenominator": 250000,
                            "tileSize": [
                                256,
                                256
                            ],
                            "topLeftCorner": [
                                10000000.0, -1000000.0
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "identifier": "8",
                            "matrixSize": [
                                604,
                                965
                            ],
                            "scaleDenominator": 100000,
                            "tileSize": [
                                256,
                                256
                            ],
                            "topLeftCorner": [
                                10000000.0, -1000000.0
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "identifier": "9",
                            "matrixSize": [
                                1208,
                                1929
                            ],
                            "scaleDenominator": 50000,
                            "tileSize": [
                                256,
                                256
                            ],
                            "topLeftCorner": [
                                10000000.0, -1000000.0
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "identifier": "10",
                            "matrixSize": [
                                3858,
                                2415
                            ],
                            "scaleDenominator": 25000,
                            "tileSize": [
                                256,
                                256
                            ],
                            "topLeftCorner": [
                                10000000.0, -1000000.0
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "identifier": "11",
                            "matrixSize": [
                                6037,
                                9645
                            ],
                            "scaleDenominator": 10000,
                            "tileSize": [
                                256,
                                256
                            ],
                            "topLeftCorner": [
                                10000000.0, -1000000.0
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "identifier": "12",
                            "matrixSize": [
                                12074,
                                19289
                            ],
                            "scaleDenominator": 5000,
                            "tileSize": [
                                256,
                                256
                            ],
                            "topLeftCorner": [
                                10000000.0, -1000000.0
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "identifier": "13",
                            "matrixSize": [
                                24147,
                                38578
                            ],
                            "scaleDenominator": 2500,
                            "tileSize": [
                                256,
                                256
                            ],
                            "topLeftCorner": [
                                10000000.0, -1000000.0
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "identifier": "14",
                            "matrixSize": [
                                60366,
                                96443
                            ],
                            "scaleDenominator": 1000,
                            "tileSize": [
                                256,
                                256
                            ],
                            "topLeftCorner": [
                                10000000.0, -1000000.0
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "identifier": "15",
                            "matrixSize": [
                                120732,
                                192886
                            ],
                            "scaleDenominator": 500,
                            "tileSize": [
                                256,
                                256
                            ],
                            "topLeftCorner": [
                                10000000.0, -1000000.0
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "identifier": "16",
                            "matrixSize": [
                                241463,
                                385771
                            ],
                            "scaleDenominator": 250,
                            "tileSize": [
                                256,
                                256
                            ],
                            "topLeftCorner": [
                                10000000.0, -1000000.0
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you stated it could be a serverside limitation (check for smaller areas) or a rendering limitation (e.g. set all values higher/smaller in `tileSize` compared to `matrixSze`)

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I don't think it's a server side limitation as I can consume the EPSG:3857 projection from the same layer using OSM tile convention and render full maps. I can also construct urls to obtain single tiles so can confirm the tile size is correct. I suspect I'm missing a subtle issue when creating the JSON layer definition as QGIS has no issues consuming the layer in that projection.